# Outputting Relation after Select - Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a laravel application and I've created a relationship between one table and another.

**The relationship is a hasOne on my OrderDetail Model**

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Customer', 'CU_ACC_CODE', 'OD_ACCOUNT');
}
```

**I'm performing a query on my OrderDetail**

```
    $orders = OrderDetail::where('OD_ENTRY_TYPE','S')
                        ->where('OD_STATUS','0')
                        ->where('OD_QTYRESERVED','<>','0')
                        ->select(
                            DB::raw('CASE WHEN SUM(OD_QTYORD)=SUM(OD_QTYRESERVED)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FullAllocated'),
                            'OD_ORDER_NUMBER',
                            DB::raw('SUM(OD_QTYORD) AS Ordered'),
                            DB::raw('SUM(OD_QTYRESERVED) AS Allocated')
                            )
                        ->with(['customer' => function($query) {
                            $query->select('CUNAME');
                        }])
                        ->groupBy('OD_ORDER_NUMBER')->get();

    dd($orders);
```

And I'm not getting anything back from the customer relation?

The result is null, but I know the relationship is indeed working and there is a link between the two.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you get any data without relation pls check!!

Comment: I get all the data in my raw queries above.. it's the customer relation that isn't showing the CUNAME